# TDD Hackerrank: Library Fines

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

From [this hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/library-fine):

> Problem Statement
>
> The Head Librarian at a library wants you to make a program that
>   calculates the fine for returning the book after the return date. You
>   are given the actual and the expected return dates. Calculate the fine
>   as follows:
>
> - If the book is returned on or before the expected return date, no fine
>     will be charged, in other words fine is 0.
> - If the book is returned in
>     the same calendar month as the expected return date, Fine = 15 Hackos
>     × Number of late days
> - If the book is not returned in the same calendar
>     month but in the same calendar year as the expected return date, Fine
>     = 500 Hackos × Number of late months
> - If the book is not returned in the same calendar year, the fine is fixed at 10000 Hackos. Input
>
> You are given the actual and the expected return dates in D M Y format in
>   two separate lines. The first line contains the D M Y values for the
>   actual return date and the next line contains the D M Y values for the
>   expected return date.

My development philosophy was to TDD this. First write code that reads the date correctly, then start implementing the test cases from the problem statement.

I did not put anything in a separate class.

My code passed all their test cases but looks ugly as heck. Any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated!

```
import datetime

def testFine(dueDate, returnDate, actualFine):
    fine = getFine(dueDate, returnDate)
    if (fine != actualFine):
        print( "Test FAILED for duedate %s and returnDate %s with fine: %d but expected:%d." %( dueDate, returnDate, fine, actualFine) )


    else:
       print( "Test passed for duedate %s and returnDate %s with fine: %d." % ( dueDate, returnDate, fine) )

def tests():

    #If the book is not returned in the same calendar year, the fine is fixed at 10000 Hackos.
    testFine(datetime.date(2015,5,5), datetime.date(2016,5,6),10000)

    #If the book is returned on or before the expected return date, no fine will be charged, in other words fine is 0.
    testFine(datetime.date(2015,5,5), datetime.date(2015,5,5),0)
    testFine(datetime.date(2015,5,5), datetime.date(2015,5,3),0)
    #If the book is returned in the same calendar month as the expected return date, Fine = 15 Hackos × Number of late days

    testFine(datetime.date(2015,5,5), datetime.date(2015,5,6),15)
    testFine(datetime.date(2015,2,5), datetime.date(2015,2,10),75)

    #If the book is not returned in the same calendar month but in the same calendar year as the expected return date, Fine = 500 Hackos × Number of late months

    testFine(datetime.date(2015,2,5), datetime.date(2015,3,1),500)
    testFine(datetime.date(2015,2,5), datetime.date(2015,6,1),2000)


def getFine(dueDate, returnDate):

    if (returnDate.year > dueDate.year):
        return 10000

    if (returnDate.year == dueDate.year and returnDate.month == dueDate.month and returnDate.day > dueDate.day):
        return 15*(returnDate.day-dueDate.day)

    if (returnDate.year == dueDate.year and returnDate.month > dueDate.month):
        return 500*(returnDate.month-dueDate.month)

    return 0

def getDateFromCin():
    s = input()
    nums = [int(n) for n in s.split(" ")]
    return datetime.date(nums[2], nums[1],nums[0])


def testFunc():
    testline = input()

    print (testline + "test")
    return

def cinMain():
    returnDate = getDateFromCin()
    dueDate = getDateFromCin()
    fine = getFine(dueDate, returnDate)
    print (fine)

def main():
    tests()

cinMain()
```

Comment: Don't check out a book near the end of the year at this library. If your book is due on December 31, being late one day apparently costs you 10000 Hackos.

Comment: @Brandin the bright side is you can keep it for another year! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Avoid so many temporary variables**

In Python, temporary variables are used only if they benefit readability, not if they hurt it:

```
def getDateFromCin():
    s = input()
    nums = [int(n) for n in s.split(" ")]
    return datetime.date(nums[2], nums[1],nums[0])
```

Becomes:

```
def getDateFromCin():
    nums = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
    return datetime.date(nums[2], nums[1], nums[0])
```

Actually, @QPaysTaxes suggested to use the splat (`*`) operator, and I also think it is a good idea, this shortens to function further to just:

```
return datetime.date(* [int(n) for n in reverse(input().split(" "))])
```

And:

```
def testFunc():
    testline = input()

    print (testline + "test")
    return
```

Becomes:

```
def testFunc():
    print (input() + "test")
    # return is not needed
```

And:

```
def cinMain():
    returnDate = getDateFromCin()
    dueDate = getDateFromCin()
    fine = getFine(dueDate, returnDate)
    print (fine)
```

Becomes:

```
def cinMain():
    returnDate = getDateFromCin()
    dueDate = getDateFromCin()
    print( getFine(dueDate, returnDate) )
```

Small simplifications like this are nothing interesting on their own but when you make a lot of them they start to add up making the code cleaner.

**Simplify your booleans**

```
if (returnDate.year == dueDate.year and returnDate.month == dueDate.month and returnDate.day > dueDate.day):
    return 15*(returnDate.day-dueDate.day)
```

If you got here, then `returnDate.year == dueDate.year` is surely `True`, as `True and x == x` you can simplify:

```
if (returnDate.month == dueDate.month and returnDate.day > dueDate.day):
        return 15*(returnDate.day-dueDate.day)
```

Remember to add:

```
if returnDate <= dueDate:
    return 0
```

At the start of the function to preserve correctness.

**Use a testing framework**

You made some work to run the automated tests, but there are already tools for that, I suggest `doctest`, it is very easy to use and doubles as documentation:

```
def book_return_fine(dueDate, returnDate):
    """
    >>> book_return_fine(datetime.date(2015,5,5), datetime.date(2016,5,6))
    10000
    """
    if (returnDate.year > dueDate.year):
        return 10000

    if (returnDate.month == dueDate.month and returnDate.day > dueDate.day):
        return 15*(returnDate.day-dueDate.day)

    if (returnDate.month > dueDate.month):
        return 500*(returnDate.month-dueDate.month)

    return 0
```

Just add `import doctest` at the start and `doctest.testmod()` at the end.

**Naming**

Naming is hard, I really do not like your names.

- `get` is a specific OO concept and gives almost no info about what the function does.
- `cin` is a `C++` term, not everyone may remember what it stands for.
- `nums` well, if you convert them to `int` they are `nums` but this really does not give me much info...
- `snake_case` is the common Python naming style, not `camelCase`.

**Spacing**

Asinnaturallanguage,spacingthingsouthelpsthereaderreadfasterandeasier.

> As in natural language, spacing things out helps the reader read faster and easier.

For example:

```
return 15*(returnDate.day-dueDate.day)
```

Becomes:

```
return 15 * (returnDate.day - dueDate.day)
```

Comment: @enderland You are welcome

Comment: @Caridorc Your answer is good but I might miss something. I have the feeling that situations where "returnDate.year < dueDate.year" are not always handled properly (because of the "returnDate.year == dueDate.year" check you have removed).

Comment: @Josay I wrote a test-suite for this and my code passes it, if you can give me a specific failing example I may fix my code for it and include it in the suite

Answer (score 1):

You're using the old `%` formatting, the new style you should use is `str.format`.

```
if (fine != actualFine):
    print("Test FAILED for duedate {} and returnDate {} with fine: {} but expected:{}.".format(dueDate, returnDate, fine, actualFine))
```

You don't need to care what type your data is, as long as it can be turned into a string using `str` or `repr` then Python can interpret it to insert in your string here in place of the `{}`s.

You can leave out the brackets around your `if` tests, `if returnDate.year > dueDate.year:` works fine and is more Pythonic. You'd only really need brackets to separate out the order of operations correctly, eg `if (A and B) or C:`

Consider setting up 10000, 15 and 500 as constants. `YEARLY_FINE`, `MONTHLY_FINE` and `DAILY_FINE` are much more readable values to calculate with.